# How to import fetch to my app.js in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm working on a project in NodeJS that takes coords from a JSON `data.json` and then uses that coords to bring the weather, and then that data of the weather, to write it into another JSON.
The issue here is that my function uses and wait fetch, and that gives me an error that says **fetch is not defined** so, I did what a question here said, I downloaded fetch, I imported it and now its says that I need to type
`"type": "module"` in my `package.json`, so I did and now it says that my `var fs=require('fs'` is not defined :c I'm using filesystem to create that another JSON, any help is welcomed, thank you c: here's my `app.js`

```
var fs = require('fs')
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const api_key = '******'

async function calcWeather(){ 
    const info = await fetch('./data.json') // fetch editable c:
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    });    
    for (var i in info) {
        const lat = info[i][0].latjson;
        const long = info[i][0].lonjson;
        const base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
        
        fetch(base)
        .then((responses) => {
        return responses.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            var myObject = {  
                Latitud: data.coord.lat,
                Longitud: data.coord.lon,
                Temperatura: data.main.temp, 
                Ciudad: data.name, 
                Humedad: data.main.humidity,
                Descripcion: data.weather[0].description,
            };
            // convert JSON object to a string  
            const _myObject = JSON.stringify(myObject);
            /* console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject)) */
            // write file to disk
            fs.writeFileSync('data2.json', _myObject, 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`File is written successfully!`);
                }
            });
            fs.writeFile('data.txt', _myObject,'utf8', (err) => {
                if (!err){
                    console.log(`Written succesfully! c:`)
                }
            })
        });   
    }   
};
calcWeather()
```

and here's my JSON

```
[
    [
      {
        "latjson": 21.1524,
        "lonjson": -101.7108
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "latjson": 19.4328, 
        "lonjson":  -99.1346
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "latjson": 20.6605,
        "lonjson": -103.3525
      }
    ]
  ]
```

and here's my package.json c:

```
  "name": "node-js-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot use `commonjs` and `es6 modules` at the same time. you either use `require()` or `import` but not both. Try with `import fs from "fs"` and set it to `module`

Comment: What is your API key? Guess you need to use require instead of import. Also, switch from var -> const/let

Comment: Thank you both very much! now it says it can't read .json files :c at ``` const info = await fetch('./data.json')  ```, any idea? @Ifaruki @DraganS

Comment: @mrtnjf is the file on your own machine?

Comment: @Ifaruki yes it is

Answer (score 1):

You can't import ES6 module in `common.js`

You have to rename your file to have a `.mjs`

You can create a file called `insert_whatever_name_you_want.mjs`

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

fetch('https://google.com')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text))
```

Run it with `node app.mjs`

Further reading: https://techsparx.com/nodejs/esnext/esmodules-from-commonjs.html